# 2.5V Shunt regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, shunt

I need a 2.5V regulator (http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM285-D.PDF) with a 3.3V power supply and a variable load (3kOhm up to 60kOhm). How can I calculate the dissipating resistance (see the voltage reference circuit in the datasheet)?

Comment: 1: Dimensionless values of "load" make no sense.  2: Why do you need a shunt regulator?  Why not a linear pass regulator?  3: What is the "dissipating resistance" in this context?  -1 for ambiguous and sloppy question.

Comment: Load is in Ohm, I need Shunt reg because of very low current. The dissipating resistance is a resistance in serie with the shunt that dissipate power. Why Wouter understood my questions?

Comment: @OlinLathrop can you answer me?

Comment: Yes I can.  No I won't. Instead of fixing issues with your question, you decided to get snarky instead. I have a lot of things I can chose to do with my free time, so I don't have to spend it helping those that have shown disrespect. Next time remember who is coming here asking for a favor from whom.

Comment: @olinlathrop Sorry but why you offend me writing sloppy question?  And why the -1? Is not better to ignore the question instead of offending other users who are looking for help? If another user answered the question so it wasn't so unclear. Or not? I apologize for my reply comment.

Comment: @olinlathrop I got nervous because your -1 arrived before waiting for my clarification. it seemed to me that you do not even cared about the possibility to understand. But it's ok. I apologize.

Comment: You got the -1 (-2 now) because the question was ambiguous and sloppy, as I explained in my fist comment. If you had fixed the question, I might have undone the down vote and answered. However, you decided to be rude instead. So now there's no way I'm going to undue my downvote or provide you any help. I have also voted to close since your question is still ambiguous (you *still* haven't fixed it). Obviously others agree with me since you got one other downvote and 3 other votes to close. Hint: when someone tells you your question is bad, fix it. Arguing about it will only make it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limiting case is when your load draws maximum current (at 3k) and the shunt regulator draws 0 current. In that situation the voltage across regulator and load must still be 2.5V

Disregarding any tolerances the series resistor must be 1.8/2.5 * 3k = 2.16k. Choose a lower value (1k8?) to be on the safe side.

If you know the possible variations in your 3V3 you must redo the calculation with the lowest value.